# How to use tawk.to API on hybrid mobile app by phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap, tawk.to

I want to use tawk to on my hybrid mobile app build by phonegap,
i copy the api script to my document, i try on my localhost first and it run properly, after i build with phonegap it does not run. here is the tawk.to embed code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
Tawk_API.onLoad = function(){
    $("#chat-admin").show();
    alert('loaded');
};
(function(){
var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s1.async=true;
s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/YOUR_API/default';
s1.charset='UTF-8';
s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
})();
</script>
```

even i set script to make sure whether is it loaded or not

```
Tawk_API.onLoad = function(){
    $("#chat-admin").show();
    alert('loaded');
};
```

but still the script does not load on my hybrid mobile app.
please any one may help?

Answer (score 1):

Today i talk with support of tawkto, and they say that is not posible.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to implement tawk.to into Cordova's application is chat's direct link which you can find under the chat widget settings in the tawk.to dashboard.

1. Get the chat's direct link
2. use it in iFrame in view where you want the chat to be

Downsides to this solution is that you do not have any control over the chat. You can not prefill fields or add custom parameters.

Comment: sound interessant!.